# How do you display a lot of comments on mongoDB without loading a lot of data? would pages work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

for my project i am developing a forum that will have multiple comments on each post. i am worried that i will have a lot of comments on a single post and so i made it so that the server returns only the ID's of the comments from the backend like this.
i used a filter like this:

```
collection.find({}).project({ comment: 0, email: 0, createdAt: 0 }).toArray()
```

this is what it returns

```
let allCommentIds = [
    {_id: '123', post_id: '456'},
    {_id: '321', post_id: '456'},
    {_id: '567', post_id: '456'},
    {_id: '678', post_id: '456'},
]
```

and my client will take those ID's and chop them up into sections which are to be considered pages like this:

```
let pages = [
    [
        {_id: '876', post_id: '456'},
        {_id: '756', post_id: '456'},
    ],
    [
        {_id: '645', post_id: '456'},
        {_id: '534', post_id: '456'},
    ]
]
```

i made another function that returns the details of the comment given the ID. so the client has a loop within it that will get the returned values.

```
for (let c in pages[pageNumber]) {
    let r = await BlockService.getCommentDetailsWithId(pages[pageNumber][c]._id)
    this.commentDetails.push(r[0])
}
```

i will then display the comments for (this example) only 2 ID's instead of all 4

is this the most efficient way of doing this task? I am running into issues where the comments load very slowly. this slow loading could be because the template is rerendering but it could also just be bad programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out. i used something like this is on my server-side code. the skip value is a set amount which is then multiplied with the page number.

```
skip = 2 * pageNumber
let retrievedData = await comments.find(
    { block_id: req.params.block_id }
).skip(skip)
.limit(2)
.toArray()
```

i also returned the comment details in this 1 route and removed the function that gets the details individually because it was no longer needed

this is referred to as pagination

Answer (score 0):

You can use limit() function of mongodb to limit the data you are retrieving. You can load comments without getting all the data (comments) at the same time.

Comment: but how would i section it? i get a set amount of comments, but if i go to the next page i need the next section of comments.

Comment: Then you can use pagination for it.